# Genus of Fibration

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

Consider a fibration $f : S \to B$ of an algebraic surface $S$, (i.e. a $2$-dimensional, proper $k$-scheme) over a
curve $B$ (i.e. $1$-dim ").

My question is quite banal, but till now I don't found a precise answer for it.

What is concretely the ***genus*** $g$ of a fibration in light of algebraic geometry?

Comment: The usual definition is the genus of a general fiber.

Comment: @Mohan: ...so you mean $g = \dim H^1(f^{-1}(\eta), \mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(\eta)}$ ? with dimension over what? $k$ or $k(\eta)$?

Comment: Over $k(\eta)$ where $\eta\in B$ is a general point.